# No .java source files in a WAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I imported a WAR file for a project but it doesn't contain the source .java files. Is there any way I can generate them. Without them it's not possible to work on the project. I am using Eclipse for the IDE.

Comment: In case you want to convert class files to java files, go through this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451470/how-can-i-convert-class-files-to-java-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

archives like war/jar normally does not contains the source. They are meant to distribute the final java application consisting of .class files and other resources. If you dont have access to the original source code try a java decompiler tool. There are eclipse plugins that does the decompilation. e.g: JAD (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/)

Answer (score 4):

`war` is generally deployable build for java web application, and it contains compiled classes (not the sources, unless customized to include which is not a requirement generally)